# how to integrate new WIFI devices to the HOMEY (without supporting app)

Tags: integration, homey

Usually devices may be integrated to the Homey when there exist supporting Homey app for them. In special cases it is possible without (simple zigbee z-wawe on/off devices).
I would like to integrate viessmann devices to the homey. it should be able to turn on/off device and set the temperature.

Link for possible information related to viessmann API.

Anyone idea how to do it?
Anyone who can do it? Even for reward...

Answer (score 0):

I've checked but indeed there currently is no Viessmann app available for Homey.

If you have prior knowledge with programming, specifically with Javascript, it is possible to create a Homey app yourselves, the best place to get started with Homey apps is in de Homey apps SDK https://apps.developer.homey.app/the-basics/getting-started.

It is also possible to ask the community for help, or ask for an app request https://community.homey.app/c/apps/7.

Comment: Hi Bouke, thank you for your advice. I am not able to make an app by myself. I may try to ask the community. Anyhow, are YOU able to programme it in Java? I mean to make an app for viessmann devices.